# How to generate YAML from Pipeline on Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As you can see the following screenshot. I was able to view the whole YAML content for the whole Pipeline settings before. Recently, I was not able to see it. The **View YAML** link become GRAY now.

[image: View YAML]

I tried to delete everything in my pipelines. The **View YAML** still not shown.

[image]

Is this feature broken or something? How can I enable this?

Comment: probably some of the settings are incorrect? can you verify none of the steps have errors? another thing to test - create a new empty build and try viewing yaml there. I dont think you can turn yaml off right now, it left preview. so I dont think there is a way to disable that.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I do used one 3rd party extensions in my pipelines. Is that matter? I also tried to remove almost all tasks. The **View YAML** button still disabled.

Comment: no, that should not matter. try creating a new build, try another browser, try incognito mode

Comment: @4c74356b41I tried everything. All failed.

Comment: probably worth asking [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), looks like a bug or something

Comment: @4c74356b41 I posted. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/556852/unable-to-generate-yaml-from-azure-pipelines.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to generate YAML from Pipeline on Azure Pipelines

Indeed, this is an issue, which already reported by other user a few days ago.

Ticket: ["View YAML" button is disabled](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/549639/view-yaml-button-is-disabled.html)

And Daniel A. Schilling also provided a workaround for this issue:

> 1. Install the "React Developer Tools" Chrome extension.
> 2. Navigate to your build definition in Chrome.
> 3. Press F12 to open Developer Tools.
> 4. Switch to the React tab of DevTools.
> 5. Click the target icon (tooltip is "Select a React element in the
>      page to inspect it")
> 6. Click the disabled "View YAML" button.
> 7. In the React tab - select the CustomizedActionButton that is inside
>      the div.
> 8. In the right-hand "Props" panel, de-select the "disabled" checkbox.
> 9. The "View YAML" button should now be enabled. Click it.

**Besides**, what I would like provide a another simple workaround:

Click other tab (like Variables, Triggers and so on), then click Agent job task or other task. Now, that **View YAML** link become available:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help. Thank you!